# Concatenation error when trying to set 'xlabel'

Tags: matlab, plot, concatenation, matlab-figure, axis-labels

The program is intended to perform a DWT/IDWT and EZW encoding/decoding on the lena image. The trouble appears at the end when I intend to designate the reconstructed images with the Compression Ratio and Mean Square Error information.

```
clc
clear all;
close all;
T_min=32;

I=imread('lena.jpg');
infilename = 'lena.jpg'
figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
imshow(I);
title('original Image');
img_orig = double(imread(infilename));
dim=size(I,1);
[LL1,LH1,HL1,HH1] = dwt2(I,'haar');
[LL2,LH2,HL2,HH2] = dwt2(LL1,'haar');
[LL3,LH3,HL3,HH3] = dwt2(LL2,'haar');

I5=[LL3,LH3;HL3,HH3];
I6=[I5,LH2;HL2,HH2];
I7=[I6,LH1;HL1,HH1];


max_coef = max(max(abs(I7)))
T0 = 2^floor(log2(max_coef))
d=1;
s1=1;
sym_count=0
snb=0
ref=1;
dim=size(I,1);
count=1
symbol(1:dim,1:dim)='S';

while T0>=T_min
for  i= 1:size(I,1)
    for j=1:size(I,2)

    if(abs(I(i,j))<T0)
        dom(d,:)=[i,j];
        d=d+1;
        mask =  masking(i,j,dim);
        I1=double(I).*mask;
        p1=0;
         for i1=i:dim
             for j1=j:dim
                 if (I1(i1,j1)>=T0)
                     p1=1;
                 end
             end
         end
         if (p1==1)
             symbol(i,j)='I';        %% I is isolated zero
             sym_count=sym_count+1;
         else
             symbol(i,j)='Z';        %% Z is zerotree root
             sym_count=sym_count+1;
         end

    else
         if(I(i,j)<0)
            symbol(i,j)='N';         %% N is negative
            sym_count=sym_count+1;
            snb=snb+1;
            if (I(i,j)<=(-T0-T0/2))
                refine(ref)= 1;
                ref=ref+1;
            else
                refine(ref)= 0;
                ref=ref+1;
            end
         else
            symbol(i,j)='P';         %% P is positive
            sym_count=sym_count+1;
            snb=snb+1;
            if (I(i,j)>=(T0+T0/2))
                refine(ref)= 1;
                ref=ref+1;
            else
                refine(ref)= 0;
                ref=ref+1;
            end
         end
        sub(s1)=I(i,j);
        s1=s1+1;
    end
    end
end


for i=1:dim
    for j=1:dim
        if symbol(i,j)=='Z'
            mask1=masking(i,j,dim);
            for i1=i:dim
                for j1=j:dim
                    if(mask1(i1,j1)==1)
                        symbol(i1,j1)='D';
                    end
                end
            end
            symbol(i,j)='Z';
        end
    end
end

%decoding the from the significant bits (P and N)

rec=zeros(dim);
ref1=1;
for i=1:dim
    for j=1:dim
        if symbol(i,j)=='P'
            if (refine(ref1)==1)
%               rec(i,j)=T0+T0/2+T0/4;
                rec(i,j)=I7(i,j);
                ref1=ref1+1;
            else
%               rec(i,j)=T0+T0/2-T0/4;
                rec(i,j)=I7(i,j);
                ref1=ref1+1;
            end
        elseif (symbol(i,j)=='N')
            if (refine(ref1)==1)
%               rec(i,j)=-T0-T0/2-T0/4;
                rec(i,j)=I7(i,j);
                ref1=ref1+1;
            else
%               rec(i,j)=-T0-T0/2+T0/4;
                rec(i,j)=I7(i,j);
                ref1=ref1+1;
            end
        end
    end
end

I8=rec;

% reassignment for inverse DWT.
r_LL3=I8(1:dim/8,1:dim/8);
r_LH3=I8(1:dim/8,dim/8+1:2*dim/8);
r_HL3=I8(dim/8+1:2*dim/8,1:dim/8);
r_HH3=I8(dim/8+1:2*dim/8,dim/8+1:2*dim/8);
r_LL2=[r_LL3,r_LH3;r_HL3,r_HH3];
r_LH2=I8(1:dim/4,dim/4+1:2*dim/4);
r_HL2=I8(dim/4+1:2*dim/4,1:dim/4);
r_HH2=I8(dim/4+1:2*dim/4,dim/4+1:2*dim/4);
r_LL1=[r_LL2,r_LH2;r_HL2,r_HH2];
r_LH1=I8(1:dim/2,dim/2+1:2*dim/2);
r_HL1=I8(dim/2+1:2*dim/2,1:dim/2);
r_HH1=I8(dim/2+1:2*dim/2,dim/2+1:2*dim/2);
I9=[r_LL1,r_LH1;r_HL1,r_HH1];

% inverse discrete wavelet transform
r_LL2=idwt2(r_LL3,r_LH3,r_HL3,r_HH3,'haar');
r_LL1=idwt2(r_LL2,r_LH2,r_HL2,r_HH2,'haar');
img_reconstruct=idwt2(r_LL1,r_LH1,r_HL1,r_HH1,'haar');

T0=T0/2
count=count+1
image_capacity=img_orig*8
MSE = sum(sum((img_reconstruct-img_orig).^2))/size(img_orig,1)/size(img_orig,2)
CR=(image_capacity/(2*sym_count+snb))

figure(2)
subplot(3,3,count)
imshow(uint8(img_reconstruct))
title(['reconstructed Image', num2str(count)]);
% xlabel(['MSE = ',num2str(MSE,'%3.2f'),'CR', num2str(CR,'%1.2f %%')])
xlabel({['Compression Ratio: ' num2str(CR,'%1.2f %%')],['MSE: ' num2str(MSE,'%3.2f')]})

end
```

The troublesome part of the code is shown below

```
xlabel({['Compression Ratio: ' num2str(CR,'%1.2f %%')],['MSE: ' num2str(MSE,'%3.2f')]})
```

The error I am getting is

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

I intend to have a plot which is almost similar to this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show us the `CR` and `MSE` arrays that you're using...

Comment: Sardar, sorry, that didn't work. The error still persists.

Comment: This fact you posted some code is good, but it is not very helpful because we cannot run it (e.g. what is `masking`?)... Really, all that is required to reproduce the problem are some examples of `CR` and `MSE` (either in full, or at least a subset of what you're getting)... Please see [mcve].

Comment: Thanks Devil, I have been able to resolve the problem by changing the CR from a matrix into a single number. The CR and MSE shouldn't have been arrays in this code.

Comment: Thought so. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found out what went wrong in here. I was using CR as a matrix but it should have been a single number. I just had to bring in the following change.

```
T0=T0/2
count=count+1
image_capacity=dim*dim*8
MSE = sum(sum((img_reconstruct-img_orig).^2))/size(img_orig,1)/size(img_orig,2)
CR=(image_capacity/(2*sym_count+snb))
```